# What IIS Express options do I select for download?

Tags: iis, dynamics-crm-2011, sencha-cmd

I am running VS 2013 Community Ed. on Windows 7 64-bit.  The following is my use case:

I am developing in Dynamics CRM 2011 and have downloaded Sencha CMD to add functionality to my solutions.  I was advised to also download IIS Express. 
I have figured out the version to download but am unsure of the options to check for the download.

The following is a screenshot of the options:

[image]

Some advisement would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're running x64 version of Windows then it's best to download the [second](https://download.microsoft.com/download/1/6/3/163BBBDE-5523-416D-A293-EA0492020E4A/iisexpress_8_0_RTM_x64_en-US.msi) one.

Comment: lol...after looking back at this questions and the experience I have now, I now realize how silly my question was.